# Get List hits.eventInfo.eventAction in Google Analytics BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I want to get list hits.eventInfo.eventAction in Google Analytics data via BigQuery using this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hits.eventInfo.eventAction FROM `ga_sessions_*`
```

But the error like this:

```
Cannot access field eventInfo on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64
```

I try to add UNNEST(hits) but also error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the query below, I used UNNEST:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hits.eventInfo.eventAction FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) as hits
```

**Output**:

[image]